# How to get URL parameters in Angular2 routing code written in ES5?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is an example of TypeScript code:

```
class LoginComponent{
   token: string;
   constructor(params: RouteParams) {
      this.token = params.get('token');
   }
}
```

How to write it in ES5 i.e., how to get query parameters in ES5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var LoginComponent = ng.core.Component({
  ...
}).
Class({
  constructor: [ng.router.RouteParams, function(params) {
    this.token = params.get('token');
  }]
});
```

Ensure `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are provided like

```
(function (app) { 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {   
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, 
        [ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS]); 
  }); 
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: RouteParams is `undefined`

Comment: Did you import `RouteParams`? Did you provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: import? In ES5 we don't import. We use ng.core instead.

Comment: We also need to provide ViewProvider right?? becz its a service

Comment: Providing with `bootstrap` like `(function (app) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));` should do. `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` need to be added to `directives` at every component where they are used, `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` only once in `bootstrap()` or `providers` of the root component.